flutter app release apk does not open camera on ios after distribute app store connect
I've successfully developed a Flutter app that uses the camera, and everything works fine in debug mode and on local release builds. However, after distributing the app via App Store Connect, the camera doesn’t open when I install the app from the App Store.
I expected the app to request camera permission (if not granted) and then open the camera seamlessly on the App Store version, just like it did in the debug and local release builds.

Could you please share more details? What actually happens when the camera is not opening? Does your app crash? Do you get any errors? If yes, which are they?

So I added a validation if the camera is not initialised it will appear loading, now when I try to open the camera the page is just loading and does not open the camera, I thought that the error was in camera initialisation but why when debugging with the original device the camera opens

Make sure you have added the NSCameraUsageDescription key in your app's Info.plist file. This key should contain a message explaining why your app needs access to the camera.
Info.plist located on ios/Runner directory
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera to take photos.</string>

let's try again after you check the permissions in xcode and check the settings in app store connect

Thanks for the answer, I already added permissions on my info.plist but it's still the same, this is strange because debug mode it's works..
